# Knowing if a Delphi form was opened at run or design-time

Tags: forms, delphi, runtime, components, design-time

I have a form which can be created at runtime or design-time to assist a component. However I need to know if this form was open at design or run time, does anybody knows how to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the [ComponentState](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Classes.TComponent.ComponentState) property

```
 if (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
```

Comment: It always gets false in this case... I put this condition onFormCreate

Comment: I got it, I have to get the component first, sorry my mistake. I have that: `if (csDesigning is MyComponent.ComponentState) then`

Comment: What to do if I am in `TCollectionItem` descendant which doesn't have `ComponentState` member?